# GPS Tracker turns GPRS mode off when I change IP

Tags: gps, gsm, gprs, tracker

I have a GPS Tracker (TK303G) that can send data to a server by GPRS with an IP and Port, but if I change the IP and try to set it to GPRS mode it turns back to GSM automatically.

If I use the default IP or the vendor server IP it works just fine.

Anyone knows why is that? Is there something I'm missing? Maybe I have to send something back from my server?

Comment: I am also experiencing the same problem

Comment: @JimmyIlenloa I found the solution to this, when you set it to GPRS (TCP by default) the tracker sends `##,imei:359586015829802,A;` to the server and you have to respond with 'LOAD', once you do that the tracker will start to send normal messages with the location, etc.  
If you want to know more about the protocol and how it works you can check out this [PDF](https://sourceforge.net/p/opengts/discussion/579835/thread/c0706b88/6fa0/4068/attachment/coban%20GPRS%20PROTOCOL_COCO%20HUO%20%2020141212.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for this feedback, will have a look and let you know about it. I'm grateful. @Wafo

Comment: How is the request made from the tracker? I am unable to receive the response. Is it using HTTP method of transmission? Please let me know how you did yours. @Wafo

Comment: At the moment I am creating a simple tcp server using nodejs net module. @Wafo

Comment: I used the net module for nodejs too, irc you need to convert the data to String, something like this:

`const server = net.createServer();  server.on('connection', handleConnection);  

function handleConnection(conn) {  
  let remoteAddress = conn.remoteAddress + ':' + conn.remotePort;
  console.log('client connection from %s', remoteAddress);
  conn.on('data', onConnData);

  function onConnData(d) {
    var data = new Buffer(d).toString('ascii');
    if(/^##/g.test(data)) { // First handshake
        conn.write('LOAD');
    }

  // something else
}`

Comment: Great! That got me started for real

Comment: Thanks @Wafo. It worked for me.